# How to call private constructor of super class from child class constructor?

Tags: java, reflection, private, super

In Java, I'm trying to override a class coming from a library. One of the constructors of the class is private and thus I'm not able to call it from my class. Is there a way to work around this (reflection?)?

```
public class LibraryClass extends ProtectedLibraryClass {
  public LibraryClass() {
    super();
  }

  private LibraryClass(Boolean useFeature) {
    super(useFeature);
  }

  // Other methods
}

public class MyClass extends LibraryClass {
  
  public MyClass() {
    super();
  }

  private MyClass(Boolean useFeature) {
    super(useFeature); // <-- This line throws exception as super class constructor is private
  }
  // Override other methods
}
```

I can't just call `super()` and then set useFeature flag as useFeature flag is `final` in `protectedLibraryClass` and is set only through it's constructor.

Comment: they made it `private` _for a reason_, I guess

Comment: I doubt you can use constructor chaining with reflection since to invoke superclass constructor compiler is forcing us to use `super` keyword as first instruction which prevents other syntax (like reflection).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible, looking at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/what-is-the-difference-between-public-protected-package-private-and-private-in) and [these docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html). What you could possibly do is place the two (or however many) class files into their own package and then use the `protected` access modifier so that the constructor is only usable within the package. If you only place classes that inherit from the `LibraryClass` class it would have the same effect as making the constructor `private` as indicated above.

Answer (score 0):

they made it for a reason but you can use reflection in java to create object from this class even if it private

here is example :

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        LibraryClass copy = null;
        try {
            Constructor[] constructors = LibraryClass.class.getDeclaredConstructors();
            for (Constructor constructor : constructors) {
                constructor.setAccessible(true);
                copy = (LibraryClass) constructor.newInstance();
                break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: But this creates instance of `LibraryClass` not OP `MyClass`.